# how to send formatted text in mail of richtextBox

Tags: c#

I have text with different fonts but when I email it using richTextBox.text or richtextbox.rtf. I don't get text with colors. please tell me how to do that

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to prepare your email? I'm going to hazard a guess that you aren't sending the email as HTML so the formatting is being lost.

Comment: You need to show the code, especially the part where you configure the email message. Email clients can usually deal with html content, not necessarily rtf unless it is an attachment

Comment: mail.Body = rtxtChatMessages.Text;
where rtxtChatMessages.Text has formatted text like some blue + red lines